# Powershell Export-Clixml object manipulation

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to save an object to file, and then have another script pick up that object again and be able to use it.

I run

```
Export-Clixml -InputObject $object -Encoding UTF8 -Path $file
```

to save the object to file, but if I run

```
$object = Import-Clixml $file
```

I can't manipulate the object as I did before.

Sample code to describe my problem:

```
#script 1
$objecttofromFile = new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl"
foreach ($herp in $derp) {
    # do stuff, then 
    $null = $objecttofromFile.Add($herp)
}
######## stop, save to file #########
#save shiny UpdateColl object to file
Export-Clixml -InputObject $objecttofromFile -Encoding UTF8 -Path $file
```

then..

```
#script 2
$objecttofromFile = Import-Clixml $file
###### start again ######
#assuming object is now a microsoft.update.updatecoll object
$downloader = (new-object -com "Microsoft.Update.Session").CreateUpdateDownloader()
$downloader.Updates = $objecttofromFile #WRONG
```

Error I'm getting is `Exception setting "Updates": "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"`, but I'd assume that exporting and importing the object from file could keep the object type as it was.

If I take the code above and throw it into 1 file, removing the stuff between the hashlines, 
 the code renders. But if I save and restore between scripts, it fails.

Am I missing something silly?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-Encoding` parameter from the Export-CliXML cmdlet?

Comment: Same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything.  export-clixml/import-clixml only exports properties (i.e. no methods), and the imported object has a slightly different type.

Here's some code that illustrates the issue:

```
$a=dir c:\temp\blogs.html
$a.PSObject.TypeNames
$a | Export-Clixml C:\temp\file.xml

$b=import-clixml c:\temp\file.xml
$b.PSObject.TypeNames
```

Note that $a is a System.IO.FileInfo, but $b is a Deserialized.System.IO.FileInfo.

Comment: So is there another method I could use to save and restore an object, since export-clixml doesn't do it nicely? Or do I have to try and re-reserialise the object after importing it?

Comment: You can't "restore" an object this way.  You could attempt to use the properties you get back from import-clixml to create a new instance of an object, though (with new-object and probably some object methods).  It would depend on what kind of object you had.

Comment: Ah, I thought as much. I should be able to work it out, thanks for your help. Accepting answer.